# how to convert .ssj file or custom binary format video file into standard video file

Tags: python-3.x, binary, reverse-engineering, binary-data, splice

I have a custom binary file with the .ssj extension, and I'm looking to convert it into a standard video format like MP4, AVI, or MKV. Unfortunately, there is no official documentation available for the .ssj file format, so I'm seeking guidance on how to approach this task.

Here are the steps I've taken so far:

File Inspection: I've opened the .ssj file in a hex editor to examine its contents. While I can see the binary data, I'm struggling to make sense of the structure and encoding used.

Reverse Engineering: I understand that reverse engineering may be necessary. However, I'm relatively new to this process and would appreciate some advice on how to identify the file's structure and potential codecs used.

Custom Parsing: Assuming I can understand the file's structure, I plan to write a custom parser in Python or C++ to read the .ssj file and extract video and audio data.

Decoding Video and Audio: Once I've extracted the data, I will need to decode it using the appropriate codecs. I'm open to suggestions for libraries or tools that could help with this step.

Re-encoding: After decoding, I intend to re-encode the video and audio into a standard format using FFmpeg or a similar tool.

Creating the Video File: Finally, with the re-encoded video and audio streams, I'll create a standard video file.

I'm looking for guidance, tips, or any resources that can help me better understand the .ssj file format and efficiently perform this conversion. If you have experience with reverse engineering or working with custom binary formats, your insights would be highly appreciated.

Additionally, if you know of any specific libraries, tools, or techniques that could simplify this conversion process, please share them.

Thank you for your assistance!

This body provides a clear overview of your situation, the steps you've taken, and the specific help you're seeking from the Stack Overflow community. It's always a good practice to be clear and concise while providing enough context for others to understand your problem.